# Moving data to another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a question associated with moving data from one table to another. I am using Postgres as a database.
I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails
end


class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",  limit: 255
    t.string   "last_name",   limit: 255
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end

  create_table "emails", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",      null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Now I want to move the latest email for the user and save it in users table email column. I can easily do it using Rails models in migration but then when I rename model or remove it. Migration will fail. Is there any easy way to do it with raw sql?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: You could try writing a `rake` task for it. You could call it whenever you need to update the user's email field.

Comment: I will use it only once so rake task is not a good choice. I think about using it in migration.

Comment: I am not familiar with Postgres. For pure SQL solution you should look for analytic functions or window functions. See e.g. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/postgres-window-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html). The example below is a starting point.

```
UPDATE users u
SET u.email = (SELECT 
                 MAX(FIRST_VALUE(email)) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC)
               FROM emails e
               WHERE e.user_id = u.id);
```

Comment: You can alse use `DENSE_RANK FIRST` which syntax differs a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use ActiveRecord with fake classes just for the purpose of migration. Something like:

```
class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class FakeUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'users'
    has_many :fake_emails, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  end

  class FakeEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'emails'
    belongs_to :fake_user, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  end

  def change
    FakeUser.all.each do |user|
    [...]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm trying to find a good way to write it with raw sql :)